# Firebase Observable Filter based on Firebase Observable values

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire2

To start I will show you the code I am working with.

```
//html code
<div *ngFor="let lis of (classes | async | classFilter)">

//component.ts code tied to the html page
constructor(public classService: ClassService) {
   //just calling a service to do this:
   //this._af.database.list('/Class');
   this.classes =this.classService.getObservable();
}

export class ClassFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    public scheduleService: ScheduleService,
    public UserService: UserService) {

  }
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(!!value)
     return value.filter(value2 => {
      let bool = true;
      //just getting the currently logged in user so i can grab 
      //the key of their schedule in firebase
      this.UserService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
        //grab the schedule based on that key from firebase
     this.scheduleService.getObjectObservable(user.schedule).subscribe(schedule               => {
         //schedule is just the form: {key1:true,key2:true...}
         //where the keys are associated to class keys in firebase
         bool = schedule.hasOwnProperty(value2.$key);
        });
      });
      return bool;
    });
  }

}
```

Basically what I am looking to do is display the classes for a specific user from Firebase. So what I am trying to do now is get the list of all the classes and then using a pipe transform I would filter the data that will be shown on the page using data from the user. I am having trouble because the information I need to use to filter the classes I need to grab from Firebase. Therefore there are problems with it asynchronously grabbing that information. I don't know if there is a way I can filter the data once I have my other data or what i can do. If anyone has any ideas to how i can filter my data please let me know. Thank you!